# Modify data in Meteor.publish before sending down to client

Tags: meteor, minimongo, meteor-publications

I have the following use case:

- I have a users table in MongoDB on the backend, which is a separate service than the frontend. I use DDP.connect() to connect to this backend service.
- Each user has a set of "subjects"
- Each subject in the users table is referenced by id, not name. There is a separate table called "subjects" that holds the subjects by id.
- I want to publish the user down to the client, **however** I want the published user to be populated with the subjects first.

I tried the following, inspired by [this blog post](http://meteorcapture.com/publishing-anything/):

```
// in the backend service on port 3030
Meteor.publish('users', function(userId) {
  var _this = this;
  Meteor.users.find({
    _id: userId
  }).forEach(function(user) {
    user.profile = populate(user.profile);
    console.log(user);
    _this.changed('users', userId, {
        _id: userId,
        profile: user.profile
    });
  });
  _this.ready();
});

// in the client
var UserService = DDP.connect('http://localhost:3030');

var UserServiceProfile = UserService.subscribe('users', Meteor.userId());
console.log(UserServiceProfile);
```

This gives the following error on the backend:
`Exception from sub users id akuWx5TqsrArFnQBZ Error: Could not find element with id XhQu77F5ChjcMTSPr to change`.

So I tried changing `_this.changed` to `_this.added`. I don't get any errors, but the changes aren't showing up in the client minimongo, even though I can see that the `populate` function worked through the `console.log(user)` line.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you'd fix your code, but you might not need to. It looks like you want the https://atmospherejs.com/maximum/server-transform package.

Add the **server-transform** package to your project, and replace your code with this (I'm going to assume you also have **underscore** added to your project, and the subjects collection in your database corresponds to a global variable called **Subjects** in your code.):

```
Meteor.publishTransformed('users', function(userId) {
  return Meteor.users.find({
    _id: userId
  }).serverTransform({
    'profile.subjects': function(doc) {
      var subjects = [];
      _(doc.profile.subjects).each(function(subjectId) {
        subjects.push(Subjects.findOne(subjectId));
      });

      return subjects;
    }
  });
});
```